# Direction of view disappear

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewwillappear

I'm looking for a way to indicate that the method viewWillDisappear run only when the flow of my Broadening go back and not forward.

Thanks!

Comment: I make this-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    
        [self deleteNumber];
    
}

Answer (score 0):

If you use navigation controller you can simply check if `self.navigationController` is `nil`. Nil navigation controller means that your view controller is not in navigation stack anymore.

If you use modal view controllers you can check if `self.presentingViewController` is `nil`.